# USB Drive- Unable to write

Tags: usb

Xubuntu. This is a regular occurrence - without warning 8 Gb Corsair USB drive becomes un-writeable.
Have formatted to ext4. 
ran dd in terminal.
So tired of this. Why does Ubuntu arbitrarily change the ability for me to write to a USB drive?

Comment: What `dd` command did you run?

Comment: Maybe the following link can help you, https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035